# Using opencv c++ face detection code in desktop java application

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I am working on a project which requires me to use native  c++ opencv code in java  netbeans using jni. 
I have successfully executed this on Android studio. 
But I have confusion about desktop java. 
Please tell​ the procedure,  I searched the web but found no solutions. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start low. I'd go with simple samples at first - when it comes to desktop apps.

Take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

Also, if you consider using something else than NetBeans, take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-D002/

and here:

https://youtu.be/8Cjeq4l5COU

You might need to configure NetBeans IDE such way it works fine with your native code. In fact, all you need is to provide NetBeans with proper location of your native code. You can achieve that by setting `-Djava.library.path` in Run/Debug settings.

[image]